# How to confirm a transaction given only the transaction signature and slot number?

Tags: rpc, blockhash, confirmationstrategy, confirmation, transaction

I want to confirm a transaction gracefully and wait for it to be *finalized*. I understand the best way to do this is to use the `Connection.confirmTransaction` method with the `BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy` argument [reference](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#confirmTransaction).

But that method requires 3 things, transaction signature, recent blockhash, and last valid block height. I have the first two, since recent blockhash can be obtained from the `Transaction` object returned from `Connection.getTransaction`. But how can I get the last valid block height?

Or is there any other way to handle cases like this and confirm transactions effectively?

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I get the last valid block height?

```
const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()

await connection.confirmTransaction({
  blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight,
  signature: "your-transaction-signature"
})
```

You're probably better off using the `blockhash` from that call rather than the one from the transaction too because it'll be more recent. Docs: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getLatestBlockhash